# jquery ajax get and post to php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send data to php file and I am using post and get to receive data base on if it is post or get.
The problem is that get is working and I click to receive data through post i do not receive anything.

php code process stops when it gets to GET then I send I POST and it does not respond to it. I can see ajax sends the data but php does not receive it when GET is working in php file.

php code:

```
if($_POST['id']){ show data}elseif{$_GET['id']{ get data}
```

jquery ajax:

```
 // Youtube videos: 
$(function() { 
 $('.image').click(function() {
       var id = $(this).attr('id');  
         var msgbox = $("#video_status");

          if(id.length > 5) { 
                $("#Video_status").html('<img src="assets/imgs/loading.gif" alt="loading ... "   />');

                $.ajax({  
                    type: "POST",  
                    url: "my_video.php",  
                    data: 'id='+ id , 
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(msg){ 
                     $('#Video_status').html(msg);
                    if(msg ) { 
                         msgbox.html(msg); 
                    }else{  
                        msgbox.html(msg);
                       }   
                         }
             });

       }
     return false;
});// End of  youtube videos.

$(function() { 
   var loader = $("#Video_status").html('<img src="assets/imgs/loading.gif" alt=" loading ... "   />');
   var VideoWrap = $('#VideoWrap');
   loader.fadeOut(1000);

   $.get('my_video.php', '', function(data, status){
           VideoWrap.fadeOut(1000);
          VideoWrap.html(data);
           VideoWrap.fadeIn();
          });
  return false;
  });
});// get youtube video.
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser's JavaScript Console? Also, please add the *HTML*. Are the `.image` elements created dynamically? If so the click event binding will not work.

Comment: When I click on the image without get method, it is working.

Comment: They work if I am using on of them not together.

Answer (score 1):

first check using `isset`

```
if(isset($_POST['id']))
{ 
    //to show data echo/print something
    echo $_POST['id'];
}
elseif(isset($_GET['id']))
{ 
    //get data
}
```

Comment: There is something preventing POST if I am using GET.

Comment: if(isset($_POST['id'])){ 
 echo ' post is working';
}elseif{isset($_GET['id'])){ 
 echo 'get is working';
}

Comment: why there is `{` braces after elseif condition is should be elseif(){}

Comment: if(isset($_POST['id'])){ echo ' post is working'; }elseif(isset($_GET['id'])){ echo 'get is working'; } 
This is OK

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40250/discussion-between-gham-and-pragnesh-chauhan)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {

}

if($this->getRequest()->isGet()) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not something like this?

```
$postOrGetVar= $_GET['paramname'] ? $_GET['paramname'] : ($_POST['paramname'] ? $_POST['paramname'] : 'Param not sent via Post nor Get');
```

Simple, readable and easy.